# Kiom traduki "unit [of measurement]" (de "Maßeinheit")?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The English noun "unit" [has several meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unit#Noun), one of them (meaning No. 2 [on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=unit&oldid=50548156#Noun)) being the category of "meter", "inch", "volt", "ounces", "milliliters" etc.

> unit (plural units)
>
> 1. (mathematics) Oneness, singularity, seen as a component of a whole number; a magnitude of one.
> 2. (sciences) A standard measure of a quantity.
>
>    > The centimetre is a unit of length.
> 3. [...]

In German, while there is also the similarly unspecific "Einheit" with various meanings including that one, a unit of measurement (or "standard measure of a quantity" as Wiktionary puts it) can be expressed explicitly as ["Maßeinheit"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ma%C3%9Feinheit).

What word or phrase should be used in Esperanto to express this concept?

In ReVo I found [**"unuo"**](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/unu.html#unu.0o.mezuro), which seems similarly broad in meaning as "unit" or "Einheit", and [**"mezurunuo"**](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/unu.html#unu.mezur0o) which [seems to nicely capture the specific intended meaning](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/tez/tz_unu_mezur0o.html).

In PIV, I also found [**"unuo"**](http://vortaro.net/#unuo) ([but not "mezurunuo"](http://vortaro.net/#mezurunuo)), and as a synonym — apparently for the meaning I'm after — [**"unito"**](http://vortaro.net/#unito):

> #### unuo
>
> 1. Abstrakta kvanto, rigardata kiel la elementa nombro, kiu servas por formi la ceterajn: [...]
> 2. [Sciencoj] Difinita kvanto, elektita por taksi per komparo la valoron de fizikaj grandoj, kalkulante, kiom da fojoj ili enhavas tiun kvanton aŭ
>      frakcion de ĝi:
>
>    - > la metro estas la universala unuo de longo
>    - > en la mezursistemo SI la unuoj estas la metro, kilogramo, sekundo, ampero, kelvino, molo k kandelo.
>
>    [Sinonimo] unito.

In contexts where "mezurunuo" might already be too long (e.g. in GUIs), is "unito" a good alternative to avoid the ambiguity that "unuo" may carry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was mildly surprised to see the word *unito*. I had never encountered it in spoken or written Esperanto, and it does not give any hits in the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/). According to the (few) Google hits it seems to be a rather technical term, and I think that the average Esperanto speaker would not understand this word (if they don't associate it with Englisch *unit*).

*Mezurunuo* is easily understandable (there are 11 attestations in the Tekstaro, BTW), and in the rare cases of a need to save space, *unuo* should suffice.

(English natives, please correct my post, if necessary)

Answer (score 3):

I've always heard *mezurunuo.* When looking up units in PIV (*[litro](http://vortaro.net/#litro), [metro](http://vortaro.net/#metro), [kilogramo](http://vortaro.net/#kilogramo), ktp*) the word *unuo* is usually found in the definition.